# how can i deal with redundant property when using inheritance table with doctrine in symfony project?

Tags: doctrine-mapping

I am using the Table Inheritance class with Doctrine to make the `Doctors` class inherit the properties of the `Users` class. The `Users` class has an `@ORM\ManyToMany` relation implemented to the `Doctors` class. Here is the code for the two classes:

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UsersRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'il existe déja un compte avec cet email')]
#[ORM\InheritanceType('JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'discr', type: 'string')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap(['patient' =>Users::class, 'doctor'=>Doctors::class])]
class Users implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
}

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DoctorsRepository::class)]
class Doctors extends Users
{
}
```

However, after making a registration, when I `dd()` the `Doctors` entity, I get a second ID in the properties which is null. Here is the image of the result:
[dd of entity doctors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnnqL.png)
PS: everything is fine in the database. I have all the data

All the data of the entity is available except for the ID of `Doctors`. Any ideas on how to solve this problem and get the ID of my `Doctors` entity?